# cefsharp ChromiumWebBrowser,how can i return json object to javascript,not string

Tags: javascript, c#, json, chromium, cefsharp

```
browser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register("BrowerFunc", new BrowerFunc(), isAsync: false, options: bo);
```

```
 public class BrowerFunc
        {
            public string readIniData(string Section, string iniFilePath) {
                string Contentjson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(OperateIniFile.ReadIniDataAll(Section, iniFilePath));
                return Contentjson;
            }

        }
```

I want the method 'readIniData' return json object,not json string.

I tried return Dictionary<string,object>,but throw some exceptions:

```
Uncaught Error: System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: 读取管道时出错: 管道已结束。 (109, 0x6d)。 ---> System.IO.PipeException: 读取管道时出错: 管道已结束。 (109, 0x6d)。
   在 System.ServiceModel.Channels.PipeConnection.FinishSyncRead(Boolean traceExceptionsAsErrors)
   在 System.ServiceModel.Channels.PipeConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   --- 内部异常堆栈跟踪的结尾 ---

Server stack trace: 
   在 System.ServiceModel.Channels.PipeConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   在 System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   在 System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.Receive(TimeSpan timeout)
   在 System.ServiceModel.Channels.SynchronizedMessageSource.Receive(TimeSpan timeout)
   在 System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel.Receive(TimeSpan timeout)
   在 System.ServiceModel.Channels.TransportDuplexSessionChannel.TryReceive(TimeSpan timeout, Message& message)
   在 System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   在 System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   在 System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   在 System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   在 System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   在 System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   在 CefSharp.Internals.IBrowserProcess.CallMethod(Int64 objectId, String name, Object[] parameters)
   在 CefSharp.JavascriptMethodWrapper.Execute(Object[] parameters) 位置 c:\projects\cefsharp\cefsharp.browsersubprocess.core\javascriptmethodwrapper.cpp:行号 24
   在 CefSharp.JavascriptMethodHandler.Execute(JavascriptMethodHandler* , CefStringBase<CefStringTraitsUTF16>* name, scoped_refptr<CefV8Value>* object, vector<scoped_refptr<CefV8Value>\,std::allocator<scoped_refptr<CefV8Value> > >* arguments, scoped_refptr<CefV8Value>* retval, CefStringBase<CefStringTraitsUTF16>* exception) 位置 c:\projects\cefsharp\cefsharp.browsersubprocess.core\javascriptmethodhandler.cpp:行号 15
    at ICCInter_HZFun (test.html:16)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (test.html:8)
```

My CefSharp version is 79.1.360.0,is this version too low?

Comment: You need to call https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse in JavaScript, there is no automatic conversion. We might be able to add one in a future version.

Comment: Actually, forgot I added limited support a while back,  return an instant of JsonString see http://cefsharp.github.io/api/81.3.x/html/M_CefSharp_Web_JsonString__ctor.htm

Comment: I think it looks like only C# Class Objct which with properties (have 'get' method) can be serialized as json object to the web.How can i serialize key-value Object like Map or C# Dictionary Class?

Comment: As I said you can return your json string represented by the `JsonString` class, pass your string into it's constructor.

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/81/CefSharp.Example/JavascriptBinding/AsyncBoundObject.cs#L62 for an example of turning a class into Json then returning that. The example contains a number of other examples of supported types.

Comment: I tried this method:[https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/81/CefSharp.Example/JavascriptBinding/AsyncBoundObject.cs#L141](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/81/CefSharp.Example/JavascriptBinding/AsyncBoundObject.cs#L141),then throw some exceptions

Comment: The exception in my latest issue

Comment: You are using the older synchronous implementation, advanced features aren't supported as it's not being actively developed. You'll need to use async version see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#async-javascript-binding-jsb otherwise you'll have to use a string and JSON.parse()

Comment: Yes,you are right ! Thank you, dear~

Answer (score 0):

You can use Json.Net for this.

`JObject json = JObject.Parse(Contentjson)`;

Comment: i tried it,and then throw StackOverflowException,may be serialize error

Comment: What is the error? Do gou want to convert it to a class object or string?

Comment: i mean,javascirpt call the c# method on the ChromiumWebBrowser,the javacript receive result like json object,not json string

Comment: You can convert in JavaScript using JSON.parse() function

Comment: Yes,but i think the less JavaScript steps the better

Comment: Yes,it looks like the only method at the moment